# Issue with SQL variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

Please could someone help me understand, why when I run the below SQL code it returns an "s". But when I run the SQL portion on its own it returns the correct value "DaisyRates_May2014"

Full code:

```
DECLARE @tablevalue varchar

SET @tablevalue = 'select distinct [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[Customers].[Tariff]
from [daisybilling].[dbo].[APRW14_FFA68878_Calls]
inner join [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[Customers] on [DaisyBilling].[dbo].[APRW14_FFA68878_Calls].[Customer Lookup] = [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[Customers].[Customer ID]
where [DaisyBilling].[dbo].[APRW14_FFA68878_Calls].[Customer Lookup] = [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[Customers].[Customer ID]'

Select @tablevalue
```

SQL on its own:

```
'select distinct [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[Customers].[Tariff]
from [daisybilling].[dbo].[APRW14_FFA68878_Calls]
inner join [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[Customers] on [DaisyBilling].[dbo].[APRW14_FFA68878_Calls].[Customer Lookup] = [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[Customers].[Customer ID]
where [DaisyBilling].[dbo].[APRW14_FFA68878_Calls].[Customer Lookup] = [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[Customers].[Customer ID]
```

Thanks

Comment: It appears that you are attempting to run dynamic sql, so you need to use `exec sp_executesql @tablevalue` you can't just `select @tablevalue` to generate the result.  I'd suggest reading the [curse and the blessing of dynamic sql](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html). You also need to specify a length of your `@tablevalue` variable.

Comment: [Here's why you never want to use `varchar without length`](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Comment: Thanks guys, what if I want the value to be what the SQL statement returns, rather than the SQL query itself. So at the moment @tablevalue is "Select 'select distinct [BillingReferenceData].[dbo...", but I want it to be the result of the query. Is that possible? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are returning an `s` because you are returning the first character of the sql string since you haven't defined a length of your variable.  Try using `varchar(max)` instead of `varchar`.

However, that will just return your sql statement, not run it.  I think you want to actually run your sql statement, in which case, you can use `exec` or `sp_executesql`.

```
DECLARE @tablevalue varchar(max) 

SET @tablevalue = 'select distinct [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[Customers].[Tariff]
from [daisybilling].[dbo].[APRW14_FFA68878_Calls]
inner join [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[Customers] on [DaisyBilling].[dbo].[APRW14_FFA68878_Calls].[Customer Lookup] = [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[Customers].[Customer ID]
where [DaisyBilling].[dbo].[APRW14_FFA68878_Calls].[Customer Lookup] = [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[Customers].[Customer ID]'

exec(@tablevalue)
```

Comment: OR even better: an appropriate length like `varchar(200)` or something. Don't just use `varchar(max)` out of lazyness, for everything!

Comment: @marc_s -- I definitely agree when the length can be determined.  Sometimes it can be difficult to know the length where `varchar(max)` removes that concern.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying the the type of @tablevalue is a varchar of length one.  Try

`DECLARE @tablevalue VARCHAR(MAX)`

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1

To execute to SQL:

`EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL(@tablevalue )`

or

`EXEC(@tablevalue)`

Take a look at http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html to learn about the differences between EXEC and AP_EXECUTESQL.